# How to duplicate particle system (unlinked)

Tags: particles, hair

When I duplicate a particle system,they are linked.The make single user button is freezed.[image]

How should I solve this ?

Or I just want to separate hair guides into two particle system.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've edited the particles, if you delete the edit (*Delete Edit* button) you can make it single user.